# photogallery popup using angularjs not working but using javascript working fine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Visit 
     `http://fiddle.jshell.net/XDaEk/638/`
using javscript image popup working fine

Visit 
      `http://jsfiddle.net/36BYs/56/`
using angularjs image popup not working - i want to image popup using angularjs ng-repeat visit above link to find solution.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36BYs/57/) to add directive.
I have added following directive:

> NOTE: You need to wait till your `ng-repeat` finishes rendering the
>   elements. See `scope.$parent.$last` inside directive

```
app.directive('imagelist', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      if (scope.$parent.$last) {
        $('.gallery-items').imagelistexpander({
          prefix: "gallery-"
        });
      }

    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Rahul. Great job :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this Library. 
[angular-modal-gallery](https://ks89.github.io/angular-modal-gallery.github.io/demo)

i think this one is best

Comment: i want to open image with description also and title with separate division. is there any other solution for it ??